Is it a coincidence that the smallest bit of action that fits into the universe is close to Planck's constant?
I was calculating the energy of the lowest-frequency photon that could fit into the universe, simplifying the universe as a "tube" with a length of 92.1 billion light-years (radius = 46.05 billion light-years). Here's a summary of the calculations:

Wavelength of the photon: 8.7×1026 m
Frequency of the photon: 3.45×10−19 Hz
Energy of the photon: 2.29×10−52 J

I then multiplied the energy of this photon by the age of the universe (about 13.8 billion years or 4.35×1017 seconds), and I got:

2.29×10−52 J × 4.35 × 1017 s=9.96 × 10−35 Js

This value is remarkably close to Planck's constant h ≈ 6.626×10−34 Js.
Is it just a coincidence that the product of the energy of the smallest photon that can fit in the universe and the age of the universe is on the same order of magnitude as Planck's constant?

This seems to be just numerology. What would happen to the nearly-Planck-constant value when the universe is 100 times older?

Consider the energy of a photon being $E=hf$. Even if $h$ is constant, as long as $f$ can be any fractional or irrational number, it still seems that there is no "smallest bit of action" because $h$ can be sliced as arbitrarily small as desired by $f$?

If only one can argue somehow that $f$ must be integer in $E=hf$?

@JeanbaptisteRoux maybe planks constant changes with the size/age of the universe?

@James mathematically f can be fractional, but physically the universe has an age, which limits how low a frequency can be, assuming you want to count at least one oscillation of it.

If $h$ were different at different times, we would notice because fusion would happen differently in earlier stars (which we can see through space telescopes). As far as I’ve read, no such anomalies have ever been observed. Also note that the “Universe” you refer to is just the observable Universe. Without FTL we cannot know the Universe’s true extent.

The value you describe is not at all what I would call "remarkably close", and it is not necessary to observe a complete oscillation of a wave to determine its frequency.

If the universe has age $t$ and size $nct$ for dimensionless $n$, dividing that size into $c$ gives frequency $1/(nt)$,  corresponding to a photon energy which, when multiplied by the universe's age, gives $h/n$. It's all just a roundabout way of saying $n$ is logarithmically close to $1$, which is a statement about the history of the scale factor viz.$$n=\frac1t\int_0^t\frac{\mathrm{d}t'}{a(t')}.$$It's got nothing to do with Planck's law at all.

ah ok, that makes sense. It is not a coincidence. We picked the size of the universe to be the distance that light travels in the amount of time that the universe has been around. So of course when we do E = hf and multiply E by 1/f that h comes out.
